# ClockworkMod Recovery makes corrupt backups

Tags: backup, clockworkmod-recovery

Four backups I made using ClockworkMod Recovery couldn't be restored because their MD5 hash values didn't match. Another one was successfully restored. What is the problem and is there a way to check if a backup succeeded or not?

I'm using Clock Work Mod Recovery 5.0.2.6 on Xperia Arc.

Comment: which is your phone model? and please specify CWM version.

Comment: Also note: TitaniumBackup Pro allows to extract parts of a backup, just in case you desperately need recovery. If you're lucky, the part you need is not damaged.

Comment: @ce4 what exactly is the difference between TitaniumBackup Pro and Clock Work Mod Recovery? TitaniumBackup only backs up apps and their data, right?

Comment: TitaniumBackup is an app for backup/recovery (of single apps, etc.) that you install from the play store while CWM recovery is an enhanced replacement for the stock recovery partition; it's a stripped down system that you boot into to do firmware updates and image based backup/restore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a bad SD card, try a new one (they're cheap anyway).

The MD5 sums are generally computed after the backup has been done (assuming everything went fine).

I.e. the process up to CWM 5.x is (CWM 6.x is different due to dedupcication):

1. CWM generates a backup and stores it
2. Then md5sums of all of the above files are computed
3. The md5sums are also stored in a single file

The hard work is all done in (1), steps 2/3 are just a single md5sum computation per file and a final store of those in another file.

If the MD5sums mismatch the backup files there must be a problem with your storage eventually (most probably). What is also possible: Don't rip out the battery and reboot, use CWM's *reboot* option (files may have not been written do disk fully yet).